# Compute the first five terms in the Taylor series about $0$ of the principal branch of $\arcsin{z}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Compute the first five terms in the Taylor series about $0$ of the principal branch of $\arcsin{z}$ with a real part between $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Hint: Consider the branch of the function $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ with a positive real part. What is the relation between $\arcsin{z}$ and $\sqrt{1-z^2}?$

Thank you for your help.

I read this link [Clever derivation of $\arcsin(x)$ Taylor series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127112/clever-derivation-of-arcsinx-taylor-series) (This is another way and longer than this way I think)

Comment: What's $f$ here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near $w=0$, $z=\sin{w}$ satisfies $dz/dw = \cos{w} = \sqrt{1-z^2}$. Therefore by the inverse function theorem the local inverse $w=\arcsin{z}$ satisfies
$$ \frac{dw}{dz} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}} $$
near $z(0)=0$. Hence the Taylor series can be found by integrating that of $(1-z^2)^{-1/2}$ term-by-term.

Comment: So the answer would be $f(z)= 0+z-\frac{1}{2}z^2 +\frac{3}{4}z^3-\frac{15}{8}z^4+...$. Is it true? I just used Taylor expansion, I did not integrate it term-by-term.

Comment: Sine is odd, so its inverse function should also be odd. (Equally, the derivative of the inverse is even and $\arcsin{0}=0$.)