# derivation of a recurrence relation

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations

From [this Stack post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127112/clever-derivation-of-arcsinx-taylor-series)

[Clever derivation of $\arcsin(x)$ Taylor series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127112/clever-derivation-of-arcsinx-taylor-series)

I worked through the derivation of $c_{n+2}=\frac{n^2}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}c_n$ but couldn't figure out the derivation with $c_{2n+1}=\frac{(2n)!}{(2^nn!)^2(2n+1)}$.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$c_{n+2}=\frac{n}{n+2}\frac{n}{n+1}c_n$$

for each $n\ge 0$. Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
c_{2n+1}&=\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}\frac{2n-1}{2n}c_{2n-1}\\
&=\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}\frac{\color{red}{2n-1}}{2n}\frac{2n-3}{\color{red}{2n-1}}\frac{2n-3}{2n-2}c_{2n-3}\\
&=\frac{2n-1}{2n+1}\frac{\color{red}{2n-1}}{2n}\frac{2n-3}{\color{red}{2n-1}}\frac{\color{blue}{2n-3}}{2n-2}\frac{2n-5}{\color{blue}{2n-3}}\frac{2n-5}{2n-4}c_{2n-5}\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
&=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1)}{(2n+1)\prod_{k=1}^n2k}c_1\\
&=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n+1)2^nn!}\,.
\end{align*}$$

Now

$$\begin{align*}
(2n-1)!!&=(2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5)\ldots(3)(1)\\
&=\frac{(2n)!}{(2n)(2n-2)(2n-4)\ldots(4)(2)}\\
&=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}\,,
\end{align*}$$

so

$$c_{2n+1}=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n+1)2^nn!}=\frac{(2n)!}{(2n+1)(2^nn!)^2}\,.$$