# $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(2x^2-2x+1)+\arcsin{2x}}{(\sqrt{1-4x}-1)(1-\cos(2x)}$

Tags: limits

> Find the limit $$L=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln(2x^2-2x+1)+\arcsin{2x}}{(\sqrt{1-4x}-1)(1-\cos(2x))}$$

First let's get rid of the square root.

$$L=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\left[\ln(2x^2-2x+1)+\arcsin(2x)\right]\left(\sqrt{1-4x}+1\right)}{(1-4x-1)(1-\cos(2x))}$$

I thought it would be a good idea to write the limit as a sum of the following limits $$L\color{red}{\stackrel{?}{\color{red}{=}}}-\dfrac12\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln(2x^2-2x+1)}{x(1-\cos(2x))}-\dfrac12\dfrac{\arcsin(2x)}{x(1-\cos(2x))}=-\dfrac12L_1-\dfrac12L_2$$ Note that the first limit is $-\infty$ though, so the equality does not actually hold: $$L_1=
\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln(2x^2-2x+1)}{x(1-\cos(2x))}\cdot\dfrac{2x^2-2x}{2x^2-2x}=2\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x-1}{1-\cos(2x)}\\=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{x-1}{\sin^2x}\cdot\dfrac{x^2}{x^2}=-\infty.$$ As a matter of fact, because of the negative coefficient $\left(-\dfrac12\right),$ it would become $+\infty$. This does not change anything of course. I just decided to mention it.

I don't see how to approach the problem if we are not supposed to somehow "split" the limit.

I'm looking for a solution that doesn't rely on any fancy split ideas, but rather on a general approach and intuitive ideas. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to split via a term ensure first that the limit of that term exists finitely. And if you wish to split via a factor then ensure that the limit of that factor exists finitely and is non-zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $u\to0$, $\sqrt{1+u}=1+\frac u2+o(u)$ and $\cos u=1-\frac{u^2}2+o(u^2)$ hence as $x\to0$,
$$(\sqrt{1-4x}-1)(1-\cos(2x))\sim(-2x)(2x^2)=-4x^3.$$
This incites us to expand the numerator at the order $3$.
As $u\to0$,
$$\begin{align}
\ln(1+u)&=u-\frac{u^2}2+\frac{u^3}3+o(u^3),\\
\arcsin u&=u+\frac{u^3}6+o(u^3),
\end{align}$$
hence as $x\to0$,
$$\begin{align}
\ln(1-2x+2x^2)&=(-2x+2x^2)-\frac{4x^2-8x^3}2+\frac{(-2x)^3}3+o(x^3)\\
&=-2x+\frac{4x^3}3+o(x^3),\\
\arcsin(2x)&=2x+\frac{4x^3}3+o(x^3)
\end{align}$$
and therefore,
$$\lim_{x\to0}
\frac{\ln(2x^2-2x+1)+\arcsin{2x}}{(\sqrt{1-4x}-1)(1-\cos(2x))}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{8x^3}3}{-4x^3}=-\frac23.$$

Comment: Why the downvote, please?

Comment: SE being SE users. +1 from me.

Comment: Not clear why, maybe for some typos now fixed.

Comment: I like it. I would mention that in this type of problems one should expand the denominator first, to check the order of the expansion in the numerator. In this case $x\cdot x^2=x^3$

Comment: I agree, I shall reverse the order of some lines (blindly since at the moment, my browser doesn't want to typeset, whence the temporary typos).

Comment: @Andrei, may you clarify what do you mean by "expand the denomiranotr to check the order of the expansion in the numerator"? I am new to Taylor series, so such hints are really helpful for me to learn how to solve such problems.

Comment: May I also ask how am I supposed to find the Taylor series of $\arcsin(x)$? I know how to derive the others, but not this one.

Comment: Isn't it $8x^2-8x^3$ in the numerator when you plug $x=2x^2-2x$ into the expansion of $\ln(1+x)$?

Comment: See [Clever derivation of $\arcsin(x)$ Taylor series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127112), especially the [first comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/127112/timeline#comment_293397) by @RobertIsrael. But if you just want it at the order 3 like here, the simplest way is to plug $y=\arcsin x=x+ax^3+o(x^3)$ into $x=\sin y=y-\frac{y^3}6+o(y^3)$ (or vice-versa), to find $a$.

Comment: Also isn't the next term $\dfrac{8x^3(1-x)^3}{3}$? Where do these multipliers go?

Comment: @AnneBauval, am I missing something, or there's an issue with the calculations for the Taylor series of $\ln(2x^2-2x+1)$?

Comment: If $u=-2x+2x^2$ then $u^2=4x^2-8x^3+4x^4=4x^2-8x^3+o(x^3)$, and $u^3=-8x^3(1-x)^3=-8x^3+o(x^3)$.

Comment: @AnneBauval, oh, I see. May I ask you what's the intuition behind this $o(f(x))$ symbol?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation $o(x^3)$ means "some function $f(x)$ which tends to $0$ faster than $x^3$", i.e. $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)/x^3=0$.

Comment: @MathStudent You know that the denominator is $0$ at $x=0$. That means that the dominant term is $x$ to some power, that you want to find out. You already did half of the expansion, when you found in the first parenthesis $1-4x-1=-4x$. The second parenthesis is $1-cos(2x)\approx 1-1+2x^2=2x^2$. So the dominant term is $x^3$

Answer (score 2):

Referring to standard limits and the other [known results](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/387333/505767), we recognize that the denominator is $\sim 4x^3$, therefore

$$\dfrac{\ln(2x^2-2x+1)+\arcsin{2x}}{(\sqrt{1-4x}-1)(1-\cos(2x)}=\dfrac{\ln(2x^2-2x+1)+\arcsin{2x}}{4x^3}\dfrac{4x^3}{(\sqrt{1-4x}-1)(1-\cos(2x)}$$

with (the first term is related to the definition of derivative)

$$\dfrac{(\sqrt{1-4x}-1)(1-\cos(2x))}{4x^3}=\dfrac{\sqrt{1-4x}-1}{x}\dfrac{1-\cos(2x)}{4x^2} \to -2 \cdot \frac 12=-1$$

and

$$\dfrac{\ln(2x^2-2x+1)+\arcsin{2x}}{4x^3}=\dfrac{\ln(2x^2-2x+1)+2x}{4x^3}+2\dfrac{\arcsin{2x}-2x}{8x^3} \to \frac13+\frac13 =\frac 23$$

and all boils down in the first one which can be proved by l'Hopital (one step) or Taylor expansion and which is related to

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\log(1+x)-\left(x-\frac{x^2}2\right)}{x^3} \to \frac13$$

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the split in terms of $L_1,L_2$ it is better to continue with further algebraic manipulation. Thus we can start from the expression $$-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\log(2x^2-2x+1)+\arcsin 2x}{x(1-\cos 2x)}$$ and write it as $$-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{\log(1-2x+2x^2)+\arcsin 2x}{x^3}\cdot\frac{x^2}{\sin^2x}$$ and since the last factor tends to $1$ the desired limit is equal to the limit of the expression $$-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{\log(1-2x+2x^2)+\arcsin 2x}{x^3} $$ Putting $2x=t$ we see that the desired limit equals $$-2\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\log(1-t+t^2/2)+\arcsin t}{t^3}$$ Now let us observe that applying l'Hospital's Rule will get rid of both $\log $ and $\arcsin $ terms in numerator and will lead us to an algebraic function and that will be easier to handle. On applying l'Hospital's Rule we get the expression -$$-\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac {(t-1)\sqrt{1-t^2}+1-t+t^2/2}{t^2(1-t+t^2/2)\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$ Since the last two factors in denominator tend to $1$ they can be safely replaced by $1$ and the desired limit equals the limit of expression $$-\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{(t-1)\sqrt{1-t^2}+1-t+t^2/2}{t^2}$$ And now we can split using the last term in numerator to get the expression $$-\frac{2}{3}\cdot(1-t)\cdot\frac{1-\sqrt{1-t^2}}{t^2}-\frac{1}{3}$$ The limit of above expression can be easily evaluated (say, by multiplying both numerator and denominator with conjugate)  to get $$-\frac {2}{3}\cdot 1\cdot \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}=-\frac{2}{3}$$